# Google maps API V3 circle icons

Tags: icons, maps, geometry

i have editable circle overlay on a google map and i need to change the default white square icons which are used for manipulating with the circle to different images.
Is this even possible and if so, how? 
Thx for help.

Comment: I am also facing same problem..